# Split string value from url and use it in Django QuerySet

Tags: jquery, python, django

This is the data that should be sent to the server for query:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cnt_bldg/?brgy_id=All&bldg_type=School%2CSport+Center%2FGymnasium%2FCovered+Court%2C
```

`brgy_id=All`

`bldg_type=School%2CSport+Center%2FGymnasium%2FCovered+Court%2C`

As you noticed, there are two values from `bldg_type` which are "School" and " Sport Center/Gymnasium/Covered Court" in which separated by comma, you can refer to the Jquery code below:

```
var selected = $('#bldg_type option:selected');
var items = "";
selected.each(function () {
    items += $(this).val() + ",";
});
$.ajax({
    url: "cnt_bldg/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
        'brgy_id': brgy_id,
        'bldg_type': items
    },
    ...
```

I wanted to create a query based on those values. So far tried this, first is to split the values and perform loop and append the list. Here's my try:

```
...
args = []
get_bldg_type = request.GET.get('bldg_type')
...
if get_bldg_type != '':     
            sp = [x.strip() for x in get_bldg_type.split(',')]
            for term in sp:
                args.append(Q(bldg_type=term))

for myid in ids_high:
    getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
    response_high = list(PolyStructures.objects.filter(geom__within=getgeom, *args).values(
        'bldg_type','bldg_name').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
    for entry in response_high:
        entry['type'] = 'High'
        to_json.append(response_high)
```

Comment: why don't you post the values instead of get so that you can receive it in server side as parameter for a method?

Comment: hmmn..It actually works if I only choose 1 value in `bldg-type`. I guess the problem is, it doesn't split the values from my Ajax.

Comment: See you should receive it as List parameter in you server side method since you are passing list from ajax..

Comment: Ahh ok...so how do I do that? I will get the values and store it in a list variable?

Comment: I don't have much idea on `django`. This **[link](http://www.quora.com/Django-web-framework/How-can-I-implement-a-urlpattern-that-passes-a-list-of-strings-to-the-view)** might be helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason that you are not able to split along the comma is that comma is converted to %2C. First you need to clean the params received in request. It can be done like this:

```
import urllib
get_bldg_type = urllib.unquote(request.GET.get('bldg_type'))
```

Also, if you filter the results according to the params received in the request, I would suggest POST over GET.

Hope this helps.